# Steamy fantasy book, succubus-type character being after the "seed" of male protagonist

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the name of a fantasy book I read a while back (10 years ago).

There was a male protagonist who was some kind of "chosen one" and a succubus-type character who was after his "seed" for some grand purpose.

I think the book ended with the succubus having sex with him and acquiring said genetic material. I think it had a mostly realistic setting with fantasy elements interspersed.

Random bits:

- at one point the succubus tries to set up a meeting with the guy at a motel, don't remember if it actually happened
- definitely some explicit steamy parts

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/602699.Spanky?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the mostly realistic setting, it sounds a lot like Andrew Offutt's *[Chieftan of Andor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1764450.Chieftain_Of_Andor)* (v.t. *Clansman of Andor*) from 1976.

The protagonist is Robert Cleve, an earthman who is selected to take over the body of warrior chief Doralan Andrah, who is pivotal on his world of Andor, but whose mind is dying.

There is a witch of sorts who needs a piece of Robert's/Doloran's body to ensorcel him, and thoough he is careful to destroy hair and nail clippings, the semen she receives from him when she seduces him does the trick. He is transported to another part of the world and has to fight his way back. I don't know if this is the book you are looking for, but the scene with seduction and acquisition of genetic material is exactly as you describe. Offutt also wrote pornography, and I remember other steamy bits.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just went on a deep dive looking for the same thing, closest of which was this post before I got lucky…

A Modern Magician - Robert Weinberg

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should [edit] your answer to add some details about the book, especially the ways it matches the question.

Comment: Definitely not - there are implied sex scenes, but the key opponent is a babylonian god and his (definitely male) muscle.  All the women I remember were either on the protagonist's side or at worst neutral (eg the mall nymphs, who were involved in most of the sex).  It's a fun read, but not what the OP is looking for.